# How do I escape a ton of entities crashing my game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image]So I was making a command with arrows and I accidentally made them duplicate every tick. Now they are crashing my game every time I join my world. Is there any way I can remove all the arrows?

I've tried NBTExplorer to change my dimension but it still isn't still isn't working.

Comment: Do you know how to make functions? You could make a function that kills all arrows, then fix the problem and delete the function.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't think functions instantly run when you load a world and i cant even load the world.

Comment: Have you tried using a chat client to disable command blocks (assuming you used a command block) before killing all arrows?

Comment: What about renaming your level.dat_old file to level.dat? Have you tried it, or will it not work?

Comment: Alright i've tried renaming my level.dat_old but it stopped responding opon trying to load. I have also already disabled cheats using an nbt editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out how to use minecraft functions it was [SpiceWeasel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/124206/spiceweasel)'s idea as show in their comment above. You can use the "minecraft:tick" tag on a minecraft function that kills all arrows. If you have a similar problem I have a download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ur271uk0ia859bn/killarrowsplease.zip?dl=0) just edit the .mcfunction file (if it's like a different entity). Then put it into the world's "datapacks" folder.

Answer (score 0):

well basicily if i did understood right it will keep dupelicating Arrows that exist so if you login with console client and do /kill @e it should work

if i did understood wrong and its just spawning more and more i have an idea

first try remove all commandblocks in the World by using some sorta commands *im not that good at vanilla commansd but ik that on worldEdit you can use /replacenear 9999 command_block air

then kill the Arrows that already excist with /kill @e

***note***

that will remove all commandblocks in "in radius of where you did the command"